# Rounded Corners in iOS Sim But Not iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rounded-corners

I'm really new to iOS coding, and I have a UI question.

In the simulator, my app has rounded corners like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqCGq.png

I like that!

But on the actual iPhone, they look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEcr4.png

How can I make the iPhone version have those rounded corners? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like that's a splash screen, so photoshop.

Comment: It looks like the retina (@2x) version of the image doesn't have rounded corners, whereas the standard resolution copy does.

Comment: Good thinking, but the retina sim adds round corners as well. I eventually just changed the image to have round corners.

Answer (score 4):

That's a new iOS6 UI feature, but good eye.

Answer (score 2):

Are you making this effect by just set the `view.layer.cornerRadius= 3.0` or just let your artist cut the image?

if you are using this property: `view.layer.cornerRadius= 3.0`, these two properties should get take into consideration: `view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;  view.clipsToBounds = YES;`

You can just find the explanation in the iOS documentation.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all the help. I eventually just photoshopped them in, but I did find my problem. I'm using the newest Xcode beta, which has the iOS 6 sim, and in iOS 6, apps with black status bars have round corners added automatically. My iPhone was running 5.1.1, and therefor didn't behave like this.

Answer (score 1):

if you want your whole app to be rounded --> go into the AppDelegate and

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and add these lines of code to the window:

```
self.window.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
self.window.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Yes, I do want the whole app rounded. How do I import? And what window do I add the code to? Thanks very much!

Comment: i edited my code a little bit to show you how to import, but you have to make sure you have added the QuartzCore framework in Target-->Build Phases.
If you open your AppDelegate file, you should already have a window declared just add that code